# How to change the repo from my master to other repo without any change in pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

*I know , I can able to go to git and change the repo name in pull request on github.*

I **accidentally** did my first pull request with **master branch** and it got accepted.

Now how can I change the repo from master to other without giving any updates to the pull request.

Comment: In general, I'm not sure that you can/would want to do this.  If you change the destination branch, the merge itself might not make any sense, and there could be conflicts that would need to be resolved first before the PR would even have a green light.  Just update the pull request, change the destination, and get it done.

Comment: @Tim Let say I update a branch with the same codebase as of master , and when I change the branch in pull request , what will happen , will the pull request get notification ??

Comment: Change the destination branch?  This may require another review and approval (it should require that).

Comment: what happens if I change the branch after if the pull request got mereged ?

Comment: Nothing would happen to the destination branch, unless someone merged again (unlikely).

Comment: as it is my first pull request , I thought of letting it go ! ;)